# Java collection

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, collections

I need to solve this assignment. I am wondering what collection is best to use in this case...Also, I am tempted to give up on collections and go for a class to hold the list. Please let me know how to handle this.

>

```
Read a file (name passed in as 1st argument to program)
>
>Each line of the file has a category, a space, and a sub-category (sub-category can have whitespace within it)
>
>Want to:
>
> - Only process the pair (category, sub-category) once
>   - If a pair appears twice, ignore the second one
> - Keep track of the order of the first occurrence of each pair
> - Keep track of the count for each category
> - Legal category values are: PERSON PLACE ANIMAL COMPUTER OTHER
>   - Illegal category values should be ignored
>
>Output is:
>
>     CATEGORY     COUNT
>     PERSON
>     PLACE
>     ANIMAL
>     COMPUTER
>     OTHER
>
>Ordered list of input
>
> - Category output should be in the order shown
> - If there are no items in the file for a specified category, it should be shown with a count of 0
>
>Please follow good software engineering practices.  In addition to a working program, unit tests should be produced.
>
>Example:
>input file:
>
>     PERSON Bob Jones
>     PLACE Washington
>     PERSON Mary
>     COMPUTER Mac
>     PERSON Bob Jones
>     OTHER Tree
>     ANIMAL Dog
>     PLACE Texas
>     FOOD Steak
>     ANIMAL Cat
>
>output:
>
>     CATEGORY     COUNT
>     PERSON       2
>     PLACE        2
>     ANIMAL       2
>     COMPUTER     1
>     OTHER        1
> 
>     PERSON Bob Jones
>     PLACE Washington
>     PERSON Mary
>     COMPUTER Mac
>     OTHER Tree
>     ANIMAL Dog
>     PLACE Texas
>     ANIMAL Cat
>
```

This is what I have so far.... However, the hashmap is getting overwritten which I believe is expected. Bob Jones read by the first line is replaced by Mary later. I am wondering if LinkedHashMap will be able to solve this problem or I need to go for a different collection. Thanks!

```
public void printOutput(String fileName){
  String category = null;
  String [] legalCategory ={"PERSON", "PLACE", "ANIMAL", "COMPUTER", "OTHER"};
  List<String> mapList = new ArrayList<String>();
  Map<String, String> categoryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();


  try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;

      line = br.readLine();
      sb.append(line);
      sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

      while (line != null) {                              
          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
               while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                      category = st.nextToken();
                      for (String element : legalCategory) {
                          if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
                             categoryMap.put(category, line.substring(category.length(), line.length()));                                   
                             break;
                          }
                      }

               }            
               line = br.readLine();
      }

      String everything = sb.toString();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

===========================================================================

Here is the full program. Mohamed's answer helped a lot!

```
public void printOutput(String fileName){
              String category = null;
              String [] legalCategory ={"PERSON", "PLACE", "ANIMAL", "COMPUTER", "OTHER"};
              List<String> mapList = new ArrayList<String>();
              Map<String, String> categoryMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
              List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
              boolean keyFound = false;

              try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;

                  line = br.readLine();
                  sb.append(line);
                  sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

                  while (line != null) {                       
                      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                      keyFound = false;
                      for(Category indCategory:categoryList){
                            if(indCategory.getCategoryKey().equalsIgnoreCase(line))
                                         keyFound=true;
                      }                    
                           while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                                  category = st.nextToken();
                                  for (String element : legalCategory) {
                                      if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
                                          if(!keyFound){                                              
                                                categoryList.add(new Category(line, category, line.substring(category.length(), line.length())));
                                         //categoryMap.put(category, line.substring(category.length(), line.length()));                                   
                                                break;
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }

                           }            
                           line = br.readLine();
                  }

                  String everything = sb.toString();

                  for(Category indCategory:categoryList){                  
                     System.out.println(indCategory.getCategoryItem() + "   " + indCategory.getCategorySubItem());              
               }


                 int occurrences = 0;
                 System.out.println("Category" + "\t" +    "Count" ); 
                 for(String categoryItem:legalCategory){
                        occurrences = 0;
                        for(Category indCategory:categoryList){                   
                            //System.out.println(indCategory.getCategoryItem() + "   " + indCategory.getCategorySubItem());
                            if(categoryItem.equalsIgnoreCase(indCategory.getCategoryItem()))
                                   occurrences +=1;
                      }                    
                        System.out.println(categoryItem + "\t" +   occurrences );
                 }

                // System.out.println("PERSON" + "\t" +    Collections.frequency(categoryList, "PERSON") + categoryList.size() );

              }
              catch(Exception e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
       }

       public class Category{

              String categoryKey;
              String categoryItem;
              String categorySubItem;
              String occurrence;

              public Category(String categoryKey, String categoryItem, String categorySubItem){
                     this.categoryKey = categoryKey;
                     this.categoryItem = categoryItem;
                     this.categorySubItem = categorySubItem;
              }
              /**
              * @return the categoryKey
              */
              public String getCategoryKey() {
                     return categoryKey;
              }
              /**
              * @param categoryKey the categoryKey to set
              */
              public void setCategoryKey(String categoryKey) {
                     this.categoryKey = categoryKey;
              }
              /**
              * @return the categoryItem
              */
              public String getCategoryItem() {
                     return categoryItem;
              }
              /**
              * @param categoryItem the categoryItem to set
              */
              public void setCategoryItem(String categoryItem) {
                     this.categoryItem = categoryItem;
              }
              /**
              * @return the categorySubItem
              */
              public String getCategorySubItem() {
                     return categorySubItem;
              }
              /**
              * @param categorySubItem the categorySubItem to set
              */
              public void setCategorySubItem(String categorySubItem) {
                     this.categorySubItem = categorySubItem;
              }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].  As it stands this question is off-topic because you appear to be asking us to finish your assignment for you.  It is insufficient to merely say "here's what I have so far" without a much more specific question about some aspect of your code.

Comment: The hashmap I have is getting overwritten when I read the second line

Comment: Person Bob Jones is getting replace by Mary

Comment: @javatreble, it would be helpful if you placed your specific question into the actual question text.

Comment: What you are asking for is basically a code review. You post your code without explaining what's your problem, inviting everyone to look at it. This is not fair because SO is not a code review site, it's a Question - Answer site. Ask your question and maybe you will have a good answer.

Comment: @javatreble If you have a **specific** problem, then **you need to make it clear** what your problem is so that people can help you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you don't take into account the sub category.
This means your map entry will be crashed every time a main category repeates even if it comes with different sub category.

I suggest the following: First of all your Map key should be something like Category+"-"+subCategory
Second create a model object(pojo) to keep track of everything(including count of reputations of this element and it's first index). Read the whole line, check if the category+sub category combination exists as a key. If so then get the existing entry and update it's number of occurrences. Otherwise fill a new instance of the model class and add it to the map.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a great idea. I will give it a try.

Comment: Mohamed, I appreciate it!! I think I solved it.